# R extract time components from semi-standard strings

Tags: string, r, time, posixct

#### Setup

I have a column of durations stored as a strings in a dataframe. I want to convert them to an appropriate time object, probably [POSIXlt](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html). Most of the strings are easy to parse using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022908/convert-list-vector-of-strings-with-date-format-into-posix-date-class-with-r):

```
> data <- data.frame(time.string = c(
+   "1 d 2 h 3 m 4 s",
+   "10 d 20 h 30 m 40 s",
+   "--"))
> data$time.span <- strptime(data$time.string, "%j d %H h %M m %S s")
> data$time.span
[1] "2012-01-01 02:03:04" "2012-01-10 20:30:40" NA
```

Missing durations are coded `"--"` and need to be converted to `NA` - this already happens but should be preserved.

The challenge is that *the string drops zero-valued elements*. Thus the desired value `2012-01-01 02:00:14` would be the string `"1 d 2 h 14 s"`. However this string parses to `NA` with the simple parser:

```
> data2 <- data.frame(time.string = c(
+  "1 d 2 h 14 s",
+  "10 d 20 h 30 m 40 s",
+  "--"))
> data2$time.span <- strptime(data2$time.string, "%j d %H h %M m %S s")
> data2$time.span
[1] NA "2012-01-10 20:30:40" NA
```

#### Questions

1. What is the "R Way" to handle all the possible string formats? Perhaps test for and extract each element individually, then recombine?
2. Is POSIXlt the right target class? I need duration free from any specific start time, so the addition of false year and month data (`2012-01-`) is troubling.

#### Solution

@mplourde definitely had the right idea w/ dynamic creation of a formatting string based on testing various conditions in the date format. The addition of `cut(Sys.Date(), breaks='years')` as the baseline for the `datediff` was also good, but failed to account for a critical quirk in `as.POSIXct()` *Note: I'm using R2.11 base, this may have been fixed in later versions*.

The output of `as.POSIXct()` changes dramatically depending on whether or not a date component is included:

```
> x <- "1 d 1 h 14 m 1 s"
> y <-     "1 h 14 m 1 s"  # Same string, no date component
> format (x)  # as specified below
[1] "%j d %H h %M m %S s"
> format (y)
[1] "% H h % M %S s"    
> as.POSIXct(x,format=format)  # Including the date baselines at year start
[1] "2012-01-01 01:14:01 EST"
> as.POSIXct(y,format=format)  # Excluding the date baselines at today start
[1] "2012-06-26 01:14:01 EDT"
```

Thus the second argument for the `difftime` function should be:

- The start of the first day of the current year if the input string *has* a day component
- The start of the *current* day if the input string *does not* have a day component

This can be accomplished by changing the unit parameter on the `cut` function:

```
parse.time <- function (x) {
  x <- as.character (x)
  break.unit <- ifelse(grepl("d",x),"years","days")  # chooses cut() unit
  format <- paste(c(if (grepl("d", x)) "%j d",
                    if (grepl("h", x)) "%H h",
                    if (grepl("m", x)) "%M m",
                    if (grepl("s", x)) "%S s"), collapse=" ")

  if (nchar(format) > 0) {
    difftime(as.POSIXct(x, format=format), 
             cut(Sys.Date(), breaks=break.unit),
             units="hours")
  } else {NA}

}
```

Comment: This might give some direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828206/why-is-parsing-y-m-using-strptime-in-r-giving-an-na-result-but-y-m-d-w

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you are having problems with [strptime](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) because it is not designed to parse durations; it is intended to parse timestamps. (Some durations look like timestamps, some don't.)

Comment: @DavidJames Ok, that makes sense. Would you agree with @mplourde that it's better to format first, then cast using `as.difftime()`?

Comment: If you start with a string, you have to parse it first, by definition. :) Then it only makes sense to pick the type to cast it to -- and `difftime` makes sense (lubridate uses it as well).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`difftime` objects are time duration objects that can be added to either `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt` objects. Maybe you want to use this instead of `POSIXlt`?

Regarding the conversion from strings to time objects, you could do something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(time.string = c(
    "1 d 1 h",
    "30 m 10 s",
    "1 d 2 h 3 m 4 s",
    "2 h 3 m 4 s",
    "10 d 20 h 30 m 40 s",
    "--"))

f <- function(x) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    format <- paste(c(if (grepl('d', x)) '%j d',
                      if (grepl('h', x)) '%H h',
                      if (grepl('m', x)) '%M m',
                      if (grepl('s', x)) '%S s'), collapse=' ')

    if (nchar(format) > 0) {
        if (grepl('%j d', format)) {
            # '%j 1' is day 0. We add a day so that x = '1 d' means 24hrs.
            difftime(as.POSIXct(x, format=format) + as.difftime(1, units='days'), 
                    cut(Sys.Date(), breaks='years'),
                    units='hours')
        } else {
            as.difftime(x, format, units='hours')
        }
    } else { NA }
}

data$time.span <- sapply(data$time.string, FUN=f)
```

Comment: Here is another way to calculate `format` in the above: `library(gsubfn); format <- paste(strapply(x, "[dhms]", list(d = "%j d", h = "%H h", m = "%M m", s = "%S s"))[[1]], collapse = " ")`

Comment: @mplourde Thank you for your detailed reply, I'm working to implement & test. I'm still getting a feel for how `paste()` and `sapply()` are used in R, so I need to dig into exactly how this works.

Comment: A solid answer. I tested and it worked for me. Yes, `difftime` is the best data type for handling durations.

Comment: I've got this solution working with a few tweaks, mainly adding a units argument for consistency: `as.difftime(x, format=format,units="hours"`.Weirdly it produces some *negative* `difftime` values, which is illegal for duration. I'm investigating which cases cause this behavior.

Comment: i've updated the solution to handle your julian days correctly.

Comment: The revised code eliminates the negative values, but seems to simply take their absolute value. My `DiffTime` variable jumps from ~1600 to ~4200, which doesn't make sense given the data. Looking into this. @mplourde sorry to leave your great response unselected so long, I'm waiting until I confirm the solution.

Comment: hmm...I get the right time spans for the samples provided. Which of your `time.string`s lead to the unexpected values?

Comment: @mplourde see updated main post for description of the problem. It took me a while to find the problem records. Your updated solution worked for ~96% of my 10k records. I'm pretty new to R, so building the diagnostics was slow.

Comment: Unless '1 d 1 h' and '1 h' are supposed to be same time spans, '%j' is not the correct formatting parameter for this. Does `any(grepl('366 d', data$time.string))` return `TRUE`? If not, '1 d 1 h' and '1 h' are probably meant to have different meanings. For the sake of completeness, I've edited my response show a way to treat them differently.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have better luck with [lubridate](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate):

From [Dates and Times Made Easy with lubridate](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/lubridate.pdf):

> 5.3. Durations
>
> ...
>
> The length of a duration is invariant to leap years, leap seconds, and daylight savings time
>   because durations are measured in seconds. Hence, durations have consistent lengths and
>   can be easily compared to other durations. Durations are the appropriate object to use when
>   comparing time based attributes, such as speeds, rates, and lifetimes.
>   lubridate uses the difftime class from base R for durations. Additional difftime methods
>   have been created to facilitate this.
>
> lubridate uses the difftime class from base R for durations. Additional difftime methods
>   have been created to facilitate this.
>
> ...
>
> Duration objects can be easily created with the helper functions dyears(), dweeks(), ddays(), dhours(), dminutes(), and dseconds(). The d in the title stands for duration and distinguishes these objects from period objects, which are discussed in Section 5.4. Each object creates a duration in seconds using the estimated relationships given above.

That said, I haven't (yet) found a function to parse a string into a duration.

---

You might also take a look at [Ruby's Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) to see how elegant time parsing can be. I haven't found a library like this for R.

Comment: These links are useful, thanks. For the moment I'm limited to using base R 2.11. Frustrating, but a constraint I have to live with. Fortunately I don't have a natural language requirement at the moment. I'm interested in trying a project like that in the future though, Chronic may be a useful way to go. [Recorded Future](https://www.recordedfuture.com/this-is-recorded-future/how-recorded-future-works/) is one firm working in this area; interesting to see where you can take it when it works.